# How to concatenate/merge two columns in Pandas when one column is datetime and another is object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in Pandas:

```
        Date   Time
0 2017-01-01  00:00
1 2017-01-01  01:00
2 2017-01-01  02:00
3 2017-01-01  03:00
4 2017-01-01  04:00
```

I want to concatenate Time column (type: object) into the Date column (type: datetime) (and change it's name later into Datetime). The values in Datetime column should look like:

`2017-01-01 00:00`

What would be the best way to concatenate/merge these columns? The resulting column type should be datetime. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `Date` to string, concatenate it with time, and then convert to datetime:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date+' '+df.Time)

>>> df
         Date   Time            datetime
0  2017-01-01  00:00 2017-01-01 00:00:00
1  2017-01-01  01:00 2017-01-01 01:00:00
2  2017-01-01  02:00 2017-01-01 02:00:00
3  2017-01-01  03:00 2017-01-01 03:00:00
4  2017-01-01  04:00 2017-01-01 04:00:00
```

You can then drop the `Date` and `Time` column if you don't need them anymore

```
df.drop(['Date', 'Time'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it seems to me you can just `astype(str)` and then use `+` without `apply`.

Comment: Thanks both of you! Yeah, that's right, its faster to concatenate in your way rather than the apply method for sure...

Answer (score 4):

Using `pd.to_datetime` with `dt.strftime`

```
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df.Date+df.Time,format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

df
Out[879]: 
         Date   Time          datetime
0  2017-01-01  00:00  2017-01-01 00:00
1  2017-01-01  01:00  2017-01-01 01:00
2  2017-01-01  02:00  2017-01-01 02:00
3  2017-01-01  03:00  2017-01-01 03:00
4  2017-01-01  04:00  2017-01-01 04:00
```

Comment: I like it but for some reason this is throwing several tracebacks and a ValueError: format number 1 of "b'00:00'" is not recognized, I wonder if it's something to due with the excel file that I'm reading with pd.read_excel (it's an .xlsx).

Comment: @KMFR I think so also if it is b”00:00” it should be ok

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little crude, but you could combine them as a string and then use `pd.to_datetime()` to make them dates again:

```
In [1]: date = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2017-01-01']*5))

In [2]: time = ["0{}:00".format(i) for i in range(5)]

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'time': time})

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
        date   time
0 2017-01-01  00:00
1 2017-01-01  01:00
2 2017-01-01  02:00
3 2017-01-01  03:00
4 2017-01-01  04:00

In [5]: pd.to_datetime((df.date.astype(str) + " " + df.time))
Out[5]:
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00
1   2017-01-01 01:00:00
2   2017-01-01 02:00:00
3   2017-01-01 03:00:00
4   2017-01-01 04:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```